# Codeigniter project showing 404 page not found error on admin controller after too many redirect errror

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3, session-variables

I was creating a simple Codeigniter blog project. Everything was going right. I created a simple user controller which still works and it's the default one too. after that, i created an admin controller with login(), register(), and sendmail() functions inside it. it was working fine with it but when i added the logout function in my admin.php controller and also used the redirect method to redirect the user to the login page if he/she is not logged in to the system. but first, it gave me the error of too many redirect,s and then my admin controller with all its functions stopped working. I shifted the login function to a separate controller named login.php in the controller folder but it's still not working. I am getting 404 error all the time even though i removed the code of logout function and redirect code too but still getting 404 error.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if(!$this->session->userdata('id'))
        return redirect('admin/login');
}
```

This was the redirect constructer i used in admin.php and will work with all my functions. and was working fine before i added the logout function. logout function was shown one time i pressed that and then it gave that too many redirects error and after that, i am getting 404 error.

```
<?php 
  if($this->session->userdata('id'))
  {      
  ?>
  <li><a href="<?= base_url('admin/logout'); ?>" class="btn btn-danger" style="list-style:none">Logout</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

This was the code that I used in my logout view to make logout button visible only when the user is logged in with the help of my session.

!!importent
But now i noticed something else. if i add index.php in my base url like websitename/index.php/admin/login then it open the login page even though i used htaccess file already and it was working fine. i was able to access website without using index.php in base url but when i add login details it is not logging me in to the system. it redirects me to the localhost/dashboard page given by xammp.

Comment: *too many redirect error*: that's most likely a .htaccess issue, please add. Also, please, try to focus your question on ONE issue only, otherwise it might get closed as it "Needs more focus". Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.